# Change "fill style" or "line style" in Gnuplot automatically

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I need to plot a grid.  Each segment of a grid can have different color /style. This style correspond to value that is specified in a file. I thought that `boxxyerrorbars` style can be relevant. I created a file that has 7 columns:

```
#x  y   xlow  xhi  ylow yhi  style 
1   1   0.9   1.1  0.5  1.5   0.2
2   1   1.9   2.1  0.5  1.5   0.4
3   1   2.9   3.1  0.5  1.5   0.6
```

I make plot using `boxxyerrorbars` style and first 6 columns from the data:

```
plot[0:4][0:2] 'aa1.dat' w boxxy fs solid 0.6 nobo
```

The plot (just three segments of the grid) looks as... (don't have enough reputations to submit the image).

All segments are drawn with style `solid 0.6`. By changing this number, one can change `fill style` density. But I need that each segment has its own style, for example, as specified in the 7th column of the data. Maybe, there are other ways. I just need that segments are drawn with a style /color, specified from a file (not inserted by hand to the script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the palette option to your plot**

The `palette` option will automatically  assign the color value from the current palette according to the value of the last column of your datafile (in this case it is the 7th column, where in ordinary function plots it will be the 3rd).

```
plot ... palette
```

**Adjust your palette to your needs**

Before plotting you should set the gnuplot palette to the colors you like. 
Use `set palette` and `set cbrange` for this purpose.

**Example**

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 "white", 1 "red")  
set cbrange[0:1]
unset colorbox
plot[0:4][0:2] 'data.txt' w boxxy fs solid  palette
```

[image: Plot result]

**Explanation**

- In the first line we set the colorpalette to go from white to red.
- `set cbrange[0:1]` defines the range of the palette, i.e. 0 will be pure white and 1 will be red (if you do not set your own cbrange gnuplot will take the min/max values from the data)
- `unset colorbox` tells gnuplot to not draw the colorbox label next to the plot

**Further adjustments**

You can also adjust the colorpalette to have descrete color values (i.e. not only gradients).

E.g.
    set palette model RGB defined (0 "blue", 1 "blue", 1 "dark-green", 2 "dark-green", 2 "red", 3 "red" )
    set cbrange [1:3]

Setting the values in the style column of your file to 1,2 or 3 would give you a blue, green or red color, respectively.

```
#x  y   xlow  xhi  ylow yhi  style 
1   1   0.9   1.1  0.5  1.5   1
2   1   1.9   2.1  0.5  1.5   2
3   1   2.9   3.1  0.5  1.5   3
```

[image: Plot with alternative palette]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I came to similar solution, after downloading ver.4.6 (used 4.2 before). I used `w boxxy fs solid  pal` same, as you suggested. Also, if `style` can be, say, 1,2,3, one can use `plot[0:4][0:2]'aa1.dat' w boxxy fs solid lc var` , which works similar to your second method.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if you find it right/helpful ;) or add your solution as an answer to the question